# Display only one label of a group (Blogger)

Tags: label, blogger, blogs

I'm trying to set the visualization of a label in home page but I've some problems. 
What I want is to visualize only one label also for the posts that have more labels.
This is the code:

```
<b:if cond='data:view.isMultipleItems != data:view.isLabelSearch'>
<b:loop values='data:post.labels' var='label'>
<b:if cond='data:label.name == &quot;A&quot; or data:label.name == &quot;B&quot; or data:label.name == &quot;C&quot; or data:label.name == &quot;D&quot; or data:label.name == &quot;E&quot; or data:label.name == &quot;F&quot;'>
<span> <a expr:href='data:label.url' rel='tag'><data:'label.name' /></a> </span>
</b:if>
</b:loop>
</b:if>
```

I tried also this one, but some labels aren't displayed:

```
<b:if cond='data:view.isMultipleItems != data:view.isLabelSearch'>          
<b:loop values='data:post.labels limit 1' var='label'>
<b:if cond='data:label.name == &quot;A&quot; or data:label.name == &quot;B&quot; or data:label.name == &quot;C&quot; or data:label.name == &quot;D&quot; or data:label.name == &quot;E&quot; or data:label.name == &quot;F&quot;'>
<span> <a expr:href='data:label.url' rel='tag'><data:'label.name' /></a> </span>
</b:if>
</b:loop>
</b:if>
```

Comment: I ask for clarity. Do you want filter labels? For instance, just showing "Food" label in labels on homepage or post page. Otherwise, do you want give to CSS style just for first label?

Comment: Hi, I want to display only one label of a group of selected labels in the homepage's feed view. For example, if a post has the label A, B, C, D, another one has C, D, E, F, another again has G, H, C I want in my homepage under these post to display the label name only of the label C and D, but only one between the two if the post has  both, is it possible? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to loop for labels since you're going to show just one label:

```xml
<b:if cond='data:view.isMultipleItems and not data:view.isLabelSearch'>          
  <b:if cond='data:post.labels.size gt 0'>
    <span><a expr:href='data:post.labels.first.url' rel='tag'><data:post.labels.first.name/></a></span>
  </b:if>
</b:if>
```

---

edit after comments:

```xml
<b:if cond='data:view.isHomepage'> 
  <b:if cond='data:post.labels'>
    <b:with value='data:post.labels where (l => l.name in ["A","B","C","D","E","F"]) limit 1' var='group'>
      <span><a expr:href='data:group.first.url' rel='tag'><data:group.first.name/></a></span>
    </b:with>
  </b:if>
</b:if>
```

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work because in this way I can see only the first one label but it isn't one of the selected group that I want to display. How can I fix it? Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Sorry Sofia, I couldn't get what you ask for, you might need to edit your question with more details, maybe with screenshots.

Comment: I want to display only one label of a group of selected labels in the homepage's feed view. For example, if a post has the label A, B, C, D, another one has C, D, E, F, another again has G, H, C I want in my homepage under these post to display the label name only of the label C and D, but only one between the two if the post has both, is it possible? Thank you

Comment: I updated my answer in light of your example, I hope this help you.